# return value type does not match function type c programming linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, return-value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define maxchar 50

int numcars; 
int c;//counter
char fu[5];//debug
int main()
{
    typedef struct car //info of car
    {
        int year;
        char vin[maxchar];
        char make[maxchar];
        char model[maxchar];
        car *next;
    };

    car *first;
    car *newcar;


    printf("Enter the Number of Cars you have: ");
    scanf("%i", &numcars);

    struct car *addtolist(struct car *first);
    {
        newcar = (car*)malloc(sizeof(car));

        printf("\nEnter The Model Year: ");
        scanf("%i", &newcar->year);
        printf(" ");//for some reason the program always skips the first 'gets' so this one is here to take that hit.
        gets(fu);
        printf("\nEnter The Make: ");
        gets(newcar->make);
        printf("\nEnter The Model: ");
        gets(newcar->model);
        printf("\nEnter The Vehicle Identifaction Number: ");
        gets(newcar->vin);

        newcar->next = first;
        first = newcar;
        return newcar;
    }


}
```

I am a student learning linked lists and this is a homework project.

The function '**struct car *addtolist(struct car *first)**' was originally not a function but was simply enclosed in a **for loop**, looping '**numcar**' times,  while I was getting it to work properly, which I did.

For the next step I simply wanted to add the function bits, the **declaration** and **return**, and then enclose the call for the function in a **for loop**.

My problem is that the compiler keeps telling me that the *return type does not match the function type*.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct car *addtolist(struct car *first);
{
```

As long as you write these 2 lines *inside* `main()`, you declared the function prototype of `addtolist()`, and started a scope. You are not defining the function `addtolist()`. Thus, the later `return newcar;` returns a variable with incorrect type since `main()` returns `int`.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. This may very well be the stupidest thing I have ever done.

Comment: It's totally justified mistake, Visual Studio errors are most vague errors i've ever seen. Under GCC, it actually states in what way they are different, so you can work out the solution to the problem.